# maven jdepend fail build with cycles

Tags: maven-2, jdepend

Is there way to use the jdepend plugin in maven to fail a build when package cycles exist? I know you can do it fairly easily with ant, but I haven't figured out how to do it with maven.

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own rule for the maven-enforcer plugin as described in

http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html

That's how I did it.

NoPackageCyclesRule.java

```
package org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jdepend.framework.JDepend;

import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRule;
import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleException;
import org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.api.EnforcerRuleHelper;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.logging.Log;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.expression.ExpressionEvaluationException;

public class NoPackageCyclesRule implements EnforcerRule
{

    public void execute(EnforcerRuleHelper helper) throws EnforcerRuleException
    {
        Log log = helper.getLog();

        try
        {
            MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate("${project}");
            File targetDir = new File((String) helper.evaluate("${project.build.directory}"));
            File classesDir = new File(targetDir, "classes");

            if (project.getPackaging().equalsIgnoreCase("jar") && classesDir.exists())
            {
                JDepend jdepend = new JDepend();
                jdepend.addDirectory(classesDir.getAbsolutePath());
                jdepend.analyze();

                if (jdepend.containsCycles())
                {
                    throw new EnforcerRuleException("There are package cycles");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                log.warn("Skipping jdepend analysis as " + classesDir + " does not exist.");
            }
        }
        catch (ExpressionEvaluationException e)
        {
            throw new EnforcerRuleException("Unable to lookup an expression "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new EnforcerRuleException("Unable to access target directory "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public String getCacheId()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean isCacheable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isResultValid(EnforcerRule arg0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

pom.xml for enforcer rule:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>custom-rule</groupId>
  <artifactId>no-package-cycles-rule</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <api.version>1.0</api.version>
    <maven.version>2.2.1</maven.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.enforcer</groupId>
      <artifactId>enforcer-api</artifactId>
      <version>${api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-container-default</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jdepend</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdepend</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then you can add it to your build:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>custom-rule</groupId>
        <artifactId>no-package-cycles-rule</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-no-package-cycles</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>verify</phase> <!-- use a phase after compile! -->
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <NoPackageCyclesRule
              implementation="org.apache.maven.enforcer.rule.NoPackageCyclesRule" />
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I did it using the post build plugin with Jenkins but your way is much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: What about assertFalse(jdepend.containsCycles()) in a junit test? Is there a reason to use the maven enforcer over failing a unit test?

Comment: The JUnit-Test approach is not as practical as the enforcer rule if you have a multi-module project. You would have to add the test to every single module.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the accepted answer, I improved the performance and log output and released it on Maven Central:

https://github.com/andrena/no-package-cycles-enforcer-rule

(I'd comment on the accepted answer, but don't have enough rep yet.)

Comment: Please include any relevant code within your answer. That way, if the link should stop working, your answer may remain useful. Also, you should mention what you improved.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the [JDepend Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jdepend-maven-plugin/index.html) is supposed to be used to generate a report, it doesn't allow to fail the build on particular rules violations.

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I found as well. Was hoping for something I was missing...